# Flutter- Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'WebRTC/WebRTC.h' file not found Xcode 13

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a Flutter project, and currently it's working fine on the Android platform. When I am trying to running on iOS, it's showing me the below error.

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'WebRTC/WebRTC.h' file not found
/Users/username/Documents/FlutterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.8.2/ios/Classes/FlutterRTCFrameCapturer.h:5:8

Processor : M1 Chip

'FBLPromises.h' file not found
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.